How to use a WASM binary in an NPM package using Rollup
Github Repository to reproduce issue: https://github.com/kyledecot/rollup
I have three packages:
C -> B -> A

Package C is a react component library that wraps package B. Package B contains a worker.js that loads a a_bg.wasm. The .wasm file was built in package A but package B uses a custom rollup plugin to copy it into the lib directory.
The issue is that when building package C I'm only getting .js and .js.map files (no .wasm) file is present.
The expected behavior is that someone should be able to install package C and use it in their react project like:
<C />

This should start a web worker (using worker.js from package B which in turn loads the WASM (which originated in package A but was copied to package B via a plugin).
